# jQuery/Javascript custom email validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I didn't want to us a plugin for simple email validations so i tried to create my own but it doesn't work.  Its always returning false.  Here is my code:

```
var regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i;

if(regex.test($("#email").val()))
{
    //pass
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: what in the world is \A and \z? Not part of JavaScript reg exp to my knowledge.

Comment: @epascarello: It's meant for anchoring start and end of string in multi line regex (`m` flag) but AFAIK JavaScript never has supported them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume that `\A` is supposed to be `^` and `\z` is supposed to be `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regx i am using in my project.It works fine

```
                   var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                    if (emailReg.test($('#Email').val())) {    
                        //pass 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this will solve the problem

```
var regex = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
if(rege.test($('#email').val()))
{ 
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression :

```
var regex= /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function EmailValidation(email) {

     var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
     if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
         alert('Please provide a valid email address');
         email.focus;
         return false;
     }
 }
```

and the HTML..

```
 <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onchange="EmailValidation(this)"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```